# Registering broadcast receiver in other class from where it is defined

Tags: android, service, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have a broadcast receiver in my fragment class and I defined it as:

```
 private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateUI(intent);  //calling function     
        }};
```

and I have registered this broadcast receiver in the same fragment as:

```
getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            Server.UDP_BROADCAST));
```

My requirement is to register this broadcast receiver in the main activity of this fragment ,Please help me to achieve my objective efficiently.How to do this.
Regards Talib.

Comment: Didn't you already do this with "getActivity().registerReceiver()"?

Comment: You already have done what you want to have. You are registering broadcast receiving using the reference of your activity by calling getActivity()......

Comment: but I actually don't need it I specifically want to register it in main activity without the getactivity, because as far as I don't open this fragment ,receiver don't get registered and I want to register it as the app is opened. @KhawarRaza

Comment: @for3st read my above comment

Comment: Can you call registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter( Server.UDP_BROADCAST)); in your onCreate() method?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your BroadcastReceiver to receive intents no mather where you are in your app, register it in the [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

from the docs:

> There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation,
>   static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular
>   way. If your singleton needs a global context **(for example to register
>   broadcast receivers**), the function to retrieve it can be given a
>   Context which internally uses Context.getApplicationContext() when
>   first constructing the singleton.